# Normal Distribution Quantiles - Is my solution correct?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Probability and statistics exam coming up and I have no way to check if my answers are correct, so bear with me, please :) Could someone please check if the below solution is correct? Thank you so much!

X is a normally distributed random variable with expected value 3 and standard deviation 2. Determine the 0.95-quantile for X.

In other words, what we have is, E(X)=$\mu$=3 and $\sigma$=2

> Using that  for Normal distribution   z$_p$ = $\mu$ + $\sigma$z$_p$.
>   We obtain z$_p$=3 +2*0.8289 (from the Standard Normal Distribution
>   Table) = 4.6578

Comment: You have an expression $z_p=\mu+\sigma z_p$.  Fix it.  The final answer looks correct, although I haven't checked the numbers.

Comment: I dont know how to insert the monkey tail symbol above the first zp :/ But thank you tof rchecking!

Comment: @VRT I don´t know how do you get the value of $z_{0.95}$. You should read of the table $z_{0.95}=1.645$  But your equation is right.

Comment: @callculus  It comes from $\Phi(0.95) \approx 0.8289$ when $\Phi^{-1}(0.95) \approx 1.645$ should be used

Comment: In R statistical software `qnorm(.95, 3, 2)` returns  6.289707. 
You can come very close with printed tables. $P((X-3)/2 < (c-3)/2) = P(Z < (c-3)/2)) = .95,$ where Z is standard normal. So from a printed table you can get that $(c-3)/2 = 1.645.$ Solve for $c.$ // If you don't mind, I rather 'bear' with you than 'bare'.

Comment: Thank you all! Yes, @callculus, you are absolutely right, I took out the wrong value (not even sure why I did that...)

Comment: @VRT Ok, but you haven´t corrected it.